# Impossible to close WebSocket connection in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

The [WebSocket CN1Lib](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-websockets) offers the method `autoReconnect(int time)` that helps to keep the connection alive... but the drawback is that I cannot close the connection. Is there something wrong in my code that I can fix or is it a bug of the library?

On the server-side, there is a timer that send a WebSocket text message every second to the client with id "1234". It's only a test, I mostly copied that server code from the Codename One Academy, so I assume that it's correct.

On the client-side, I wrote this test case:

```
        String uniqueId = "1234";
        Form hi = new Form("WebSocket Test", BoxLayout.y());
        hi.show();

        final WebSocket sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/wsMsg") {
            @Override
            protected void onOpen() {
                Log.p("WebSocket onOpen - Sending uniqueId: " + uniqueId);
                hi.add("WebSocket onOpen - Sending uniqueId: " + uniqueId);
                hi.animateLayout(400);
                send(uniqueId);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
                Log.p("WebSocket onClose");
                hi.add("WebSocket onClose");
                hi.animateLayout(400);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onMessage(String message) {
                Log.p("WebSocket onMessage: " + message);
                hi.add(new SpanLabel("WebSocket onMessage: " + message));
                hi.animateLayout(400);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onMessage(byte[] message) {
                Log.p("WebSocket onMessage (byte[]): " + message.toString());
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(Exception ex) {
                Log.e(ex);
                hi.add(new SpanLabel("WebSocket onError:\n" + ex.getMessage()));
            }
        };
        sock.connect();
        sock.autoReconnect(5000);

        UITimer.timer(5000, false, hi, () -> {
            sock.close();
        });
```

The output is:

[image]

As you can see, after closing the WebSocket connection, `autoReconnect` reopened it. The expected behavior is that `autoReconnect` must reconnect only on network errors, and not when `close` is explicitly invoked.

Comment: After writing this question, I tested the same code on real devices (Android and iOS) and I got a different behavior between them. That convinced myself that it's a bug of the library, so I filed the issue: https://github.com/shannah/cn1-websockets/issues/16

Comment: That makes sense, Steve has been busy tracking a memory crash all week (resolved finally) so hopefully he'll recover enough over the weekend to look at that. If not be sure to ping us on this